# What type of fastener should I use for a hollow wood door?

Tags: doors, hardware

I'm planning on putting a bathrobe/extra towel hook on the back of my bathroom door, but I'm pretty sure it's hollow wood. Can I just use the standard screws that come with the hook kit, or do I need something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need hollow door fixings - something like [these](https://www.plasplugs.co.uk/specialist-fixings/hollow-door/5-hollow-door-regular-duty-fixings/)

> These tough compact fixings have a rivet type action that grips the inside of the panel.

[image: image showing how they work]

Basically, you need something that can expand inside the door and be drawn back towards the inner surface of the door thus gripping the door panel and holding the screw in place.

(I don't work for PlasPlugs! It's just that they make the most different types of fixings for all situations.)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you already purchased a hook, but I can recommend 3M Command products. They use a removable, non-damaging adhesive strip.

Comment: I've actually got a few nice-looking Command hooks, but the hook I'm installing matches the rest of the fixtures in the bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

Screwing straight into a hollow wooden door will work at first, but IME it won't last.

What did work for me is taking a fairly large peice of wood (the bit I used was about 30cm wide, 10cm tall and 2cm thick), and attaching it to the door with screws and glue, then screwing to that. I used my router to put a profile on the edge of the board before attaching it to the door